# How to use the case statement in views

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

How to use the case statement in views...

When I try to execute the case statement, it is giving warning message and showing the output, but when I try to save the views it is giving no output column specified errors

Query

```
Select 
    emp_code, 
    case 
        when emp_name = 'a' then 'Apple' 
        else 'dummy' 
    end as emp_name 
from table1
```

There is any other option is available instead of case.

Need query help

Comment: Your code looks perfect to me. Naming the column of the case the same as the column in the table, is something I do frequently and can not be the reason of the problem.

Comment: Can you show us the warning message? Now we can only guess. Your query is so basic, I can not think what warning it could generate. Can you give us the data types involved too? Is there a TEXT data type involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can name your new "case" computed column the same (`emp_name`) as a column that already exists in the table - try using some other name!

```
SELECT
   emp_code, 
   CASE 
       WHEN emp_name = 'a' THEN 'Apple' 
       ELSE 'dummy' 
   END AS new_emp_name
FROM dbo.table1
```